# Insert jsonb into postgresql

Tags: activejdbc

I want to create an object and save it ionto the DB

```
Log l = new Log();

l.setTimestamp("creation_date", Util.getCurrentTimestamp());
l.setString("app_name", "name");
l.setString("log_type", "type");
l.setLong("user_id", 9l);
l.setLong("module_element_id", 9);
l.set("info", JsonHelper.toJsonString("{}"));
l.save();
```

I've tried mutiple silution but always get this error:

```
ERROR: column "info" is of type jsonb but expression is of type character varying
```

How to insert a jsonb?

edit (DDL):

-- Table: public.log

-- DROP TABLE public.log;

```
CREATE TABLE public.log
(
  id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('log_id_seq'::regclass),
  creation_date timestamp without time zone,
  app_name text,
  log_type text,
  user_id bigint,
  module_element_type bigint,
  info jsonb,
  CONSTRAINT log_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public.log
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: Rony, can you please provide a DDL for your table?

Comment: Sure, I edited my post

Comment: Rony, I think this functionality needs to be added to the PostgreSQL dialect and related to: https://github.com/javalite/activejdbc/issues/640. I was trying to find Postgres documentation where it lists all the types that have this strange syntax, but was unable tofind it. If you find, it I will use to add this feature to the framework.

Comment: ok, thanks for you answer. If I find it I'll let you know.

Comment: the implementation was added, please see  the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This implementation is missing in the framework currently. It was already reported in https://github.com/javalite/activejdbc/issues/640. If you can help tracking down Postgres documentation for all the Postgres data types where this syntax is used with PreparedStatement:

```
UPDATE my_table SET status = ?::status_type WHERE id = ?
```

I will then be in a position to quickly implement it for the PostgreSQL dialect: https://github.com/javalite/activejdbc/blob/master/activejdbc/src/main/java/org/javalite/activejdbc/dialects/PostgreSQLDialect.java

**Update Jan 4 2022:**

The implementation was added to the SNAPSHOT-3.0 and will make it to a next release 3.0 for Java 16.

You can see the discussion here: https://github.com/javalite/javalite/issues/640